# Updating the Entry in geometry_columns for Spatial Table Created from a Query

Tags: postgis, geometry, postgis-2.0, srid

I created a spatial table from a query. Now, I notice in geometry_columns, the following entry for the table:

```
 f_table_catalog | f_table_schema |    f_table_name    | f_geometry_column | coord_dimension |  srid  |     type     
      my_db      | public         | my_table           | geom              |               2 |      0 | GEOMETRY
```

I want the srid to be 4326 (this is the srid of the original table) and the type to be Linestring (currently Geometry). Running the following,

```
SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('public.my_table'::regclass, false);
```

updated the srid in geometry_columns to 4326. However the type is still Geometry. How can I make sure that the geom column in my_table is properly recognized in the geometry_columns and its type is Linestring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With PostGIS 2.x, `geometry_columns` is a VIEW, not a TABLE.

Try altering `my_table.geom` to your specifications using:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(LineString, 4326) USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326);
```

depending on the contents of `geom`, you may need to modify the `USING <expression>` part.